# Weak-* convergence and continuity

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis

Let $a,b \in \mathbb R$ with $a<b$ and consider a sequence $(f_n)_{n \in \mathbb N}$ of continuous functions on $[a,b]$ that converges weak-* to $f \in \mathrm L^\infty([a,b])$, that is to say
$$ \int_a^b f_n(x)\phi(x)\, \mathrm dx \underset{n \to +\infty}{\longrightarrow}  \int_a^b f(x)\phi(x)\, \mathrm dx$$
for all $\phi \in \mathrm L^1([a,b])$.

Is is true that $f$ is continuous ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not necessarily.  If we have $f_n \to f$ pointwise and boundedly (i.e. $\sup_n \|f_n\|_\infty < \infty$) then we have weak-* convergence, just by the dominated convergence theorem.  But of course this can happen without $f$ being continuous.